# Using the API call to retrieve the coupon code on an order

Tags: api, sales-order, coupon-codes

I'm trying to use salesOrderInfo, but I can't see the coupon code returned anywhere.  Is there any way of finding the coupon code for an order?

I'm using the SOAPv2 API with WS-I compliance enabled.  My code is just a mock up in VB.NET to test so far, but is very simple...

```
Dim mc As New BMCore.Magento.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortTypeClient()
Dim token = mc.login("TheUserName", "TheAPIKey")
Dim response = mc.salesOrderInfo(token, 100000024)
```

I know that sales order 100000024 definitely has a coupon code and I am retrieving all the other order details ok, just can't see the coupon code anywhere - I've searched the response for both "coupon" and the actual code.  I've also checked the response using Fiddler to ensure that there is nothing relevant that is being returned from the server that isn't making it into the object.

Response from Fiddler (anonymised)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:salesOrderInfoResponseParam>
<result>
<increment_id>100000024</increment_id>
<store_id>1</store_id>
<created_at>2015-05-28 12:21:50</created_at>
<updated_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</updated_at>
<customer_id>2</customer_id>
<tax_amount>0.0000</tax_amount>
<shipping_amount>4.9900</shipping_amount>
<discount_amount>-17.1900</discount_amount>
<subtotal>171.9100</subtotal>
<grand_total>159.7100</grand_total>
<total_paid>159.7100</total_paid>
<total_refunded>154.7200</total_refunded>
<total_qty_ordered>9.0000</total_qty_ordered>
<total_invoiced>159.7100</total_invoiced>
<total_offline_refunded>154.7200</total_offline_refunded>
<base_tax_amount>0.0000</base_tax_amount>
<base_shipping_amount>4.9900</base_shipping_amount>
<base_discount_amount>-17.1900</base_discount_amount>
<base_subtotal>171.9100</base_subtotal>
<base_grand_total>159.7100</base_grand_total>
<base_total_paid>159.7100</base_total_paid>
<base_total_refunded>154.7200</base_total_refunded>
<base_total_invoiced>159.7100</base_total_invoiced>
<base_total_offline_refunded>154.7200</base_total_offline_refunded>
<billing_address_id>67</billing_address_id>
<shipping_address_id>68</shipping_address_id>
<store_to_base_rate>1.0000</store_to_base_rate>
<store_to_order_rate>1.0000</store_to_order_rate>
<base_to_global_rate>1.0000</base_to_global_rate>
<base_to_order_rate>1.0000</base_to_order_rate>
<weight>0.0000</weight>
<store_name>Main Website
Main Website Store
Default Store View</store_name>
<remote_ip>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</remote_ip>
<status>complete</status>
<state>complete</state>
<applied_rule_ids>2</applied_rule_ids>
<global_currency_code>GBP</global_currency_code>
<base_currency_code>GBP</base_currency_code>
<store_currency_code>GBP</store_currency_code>
<order_currency_code>GBP</order_currency_code>
<shipping_method>matrixrate_matrixrate_20</shipping_method>
<shipping_description>Select Shipping Method - Speedy Delivery ( 1 - 2 Working Days)</shipping_description>
<customer_email>********@gmail.com</customer_email>
<customer_firstname>****</customer_firstname>
<customer_lastname>***********</customer_lastname>
<quote_id>76</quote_id>
<is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
<customer_group_id>1</customer_group_id>
<customer_note_notify>0</customer_note_notify>
<customer_is_guest>0</customer_is_guest>
<email_sent>1</email_sent>
<order_id>34</order_id>
<shipping_address>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<address_type>shipping</address_type>
<firstname>****</firstname>
<lastname>*******</lastname>
<street>************</street>
<city>*******</city>
<postcode>*******</postcode>
<country_id>GB</country_id>
<telephone>+********</telephone>
<address_id>68</address_id>
</shipping_address>
<billing_address>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<address_type>billing</address_type>
<firstname>****</firstname>
<lastname>*********</lastname>
<street>*********</street>
<city>********</city>
<region>-</region>
<postcode>*********</postcode>
<country_id>GB</country_id>
<telephone>+*********</telephone>
<address_id>67</address_id>
</billing_address>
<items>
<complexObjectArray>
<item_id>41</item_id>
<order_id>34</order_id>
<quote_item_id>82</quote_item_id>
<created_at>2015-05-28 12:21:50</created_at>
<updated_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</updated_at>
<product_id>1</product_id>
<product_type>simple</product_type>
<product_options>a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:172:"aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuYmFyZ2Fpbm1heC5jby51ay90eXBlLW9mLXRveS9kb2xscy1wbGF5c2V0cy9vbmUtZGlyZWN0aW9uLWRhcmUtdG8tZHJlYW0tbGlmZS1hcy1vbmUtZGlyZWN0aW9uLWJvb2suaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,";s:7:"product";s:1:"1";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"3tDrSuCZRFCguJAc";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}}</product_options>
<weight>0.0000</weight>
<is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
<sku>**********</sku>
<name>*****************k</name>
<applied_rule_ids>2</applied_rule_ids>
<free_shipping>0</free_shipping>
<is_qty_decimal>0</is_qty_decimal>
<no_discount>0</no_discount>
<qty_canceled>0.0000</qty_canceled>
<qty_invoiced>6.0000</qty_invoiced>
<qty_ordered>6.0000</qty_ordered>
<qty_refunded>6.0000</qty_refunded>
<qty_shipped>0.0000</qty_shipped>
<price>19.9900</price>
<base_price>19.9900</base_price>
<original_price>19.9900</original_price>
<base_original_price>19.9900</base_original_price>
<tax_percent>0.0000</tax_percent>
<tax_amount>0.0000</tax_amount>
<base_tax_amount>0.0000</base_tax_amount>
<tax_invoiced>0.0000</tax_invoiced>
<base_tax_invoiced>0.0000</base_tax_invoiced>
<discount_percent>10.0000</discount_percent>
<discount_amount>11.9900</discount_amount>
<base_discount_amount>11.9900</base_discount_amount>
<discount_invoiced>11.9900</discount_invoiced>
<base_discount_invoiced>11.9900</base_discount_invoiced>
<amount_refunded>119.9400</amount_refunded>
<base_amount_refunded>119.9400</base_amount_refunded>
<row_total>119.9400</row_total>
<base_row_total>119.9400</base_row_total>
<row_invoiced>119.9400</row_invoiced>
<base_row_invoiced>119.9400</base_row_invoiced>
<row_weight>0.0000</row_weight>
<weee_tax_applied>a:0:{}</weee_tax_applied>
<weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_amount>
<weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_disposition>
<weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_row_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_row_disposition>
</complexObjectArray>
<complexObjectArray>
<item_id>42</item_id>
<order_id>34</order_id>
<quote_item_id>97</quote_item_id>
<created_at>2015-05-28 12:21:50</created_at>
<updated_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</updated_at>
<product_id>7</product_id>
<product_type>simple</product_type>
<product_options>a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:84:"aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuYmFyZ2Fpbm1heC5jby51ay90eXBlLW9mLXRveS9kb2xscy1wbGF5c2V0cy5odG1s";s:7:"product";s:1:"7";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"oWVwEWvPQ4F7TCHK";s:9:"productId";s:1:"7";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}}</product_options>
<weight>0.0000</weight>
<is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
<sku>*****</sku>
<name>**********</name>
<applied_rule_ids>2</applied_rule_ids>
<free_shipping>0</free_shipping>
<is_qty_decimal>0</is_qty_decimal>
<no_discount>0</no_discount>
<qty_canceled>0.0000</qty_canceled>
<qty_invoiced>2.0000</qty_invoiced>
<qty_ordered>2.0000</qty_ordered>
<qty_refunded>2.0000</qty_refunded>
<qty_shipped>0.0000</qty_shipped>
<price>5.9900</price>
<base_price>5.9900</base_price>
<original_price>5.9900</original_price>
<base_original_price>5.9900</base_original_price>
<tax_percent>0.0000</tax_percent>
<tax_amount>0.0000</tax_amount>
<base_tax_amount>0.0000</base_tax_amount>
<tax_invoiced>0.0000</tax_invoiced>
<base_tax_invoiced>0.0000</base_tax_invoiced>
<discount_percent>10.0000</discount_percent>
<discount_amount>1.2000</discount_amount>
<base_discount_amount>1.2000</base_discount_amount>
<discount_invoiced>1.2000</discount_invoiced>
<base_discount_invoiced>1.2000</base_discount_invoiced>
<amount_refunded>11.9800</amount_refunded>
<base_amount_refunded>11.9800</base_amount_refunded>
<row_total>11.9800</row_total>
<base_row_total>11.9800</base_row_total>
<row_invoiced>11.9800</row_invoiced>
<base_row_invoiced>11.9800</base_row_invoiced>
<row_weight>0.0000</row_weight>
<weee_tax_applied>a:0:{}</weee_tax_applied>
<weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_amount>
<weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_disposition>
<weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_row_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_row_disposition>
</complexObjectArray>
<complexObjectArray>
<item_id>43</item_id>
<order_id>34</order_id>
<quote_item_id>99</quote_item_id>
<created_at>2015-05-28 12:21:50</created_at>
<updated_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</updated_at>
<product_id>9</product_id>
<product_type>simple</product_type>
<product_options>a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:140:"aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuYmFyZ2Fpbm1heC5jby51ay90eXBlLW9mLXRveS9kb2xscy1wbGF5c2V0cy9tb25zdGVyLWhpZ2gtY2xlby12YW5pdHktZHJlc3NpbmctdGFibGUuaHRtbA,,";s:7:"product";s:1:"9";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"wRoD321eMVPMS5Kp";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}}</product_options>
<weight>0.0000</weight>
<is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
<sku>********</sku>
<name>********************</name>
<applied_rule_ids>2</applied_rule_ids>
<free_shipping>0</free_shipping>
<is_qty_decimal>0</is_qty_decimal>
<no_discount>0</no_discount>
<qty_canceled>0.0000</qty_canceled>
<qty_invoiced>1.0000</qty_invoiced>
<qty_ordered>1.0000</qty_ordered>
<qty_refunded>1.0000</qty_refunded>
<qty_shipped>0.0000</qty_shipped>
<price>39.9900</price>
<base_price>39.9900</base_price>
<original_price>39.9900</original_price>
<base_original_price>39.9900</base_original_price>
<tax_percent>0.0000</tax_percent>
<tax_amount>0.0000</tax_amount>
<base_tax_amount>0.0000</base_tax_amount>
<tax_invoiced>0.0000</tax_invoiced>
<base_tax_invoiced>0.0000</base_tax_invoiced>
<discount_percent>10.0000</discount_percent>
<discount_amount>4.0000</discount_amount>
<base_discount_amount>4.0000</base_discount_amount>
<discount_invoiced>4.0000</discount_invoiced>
<base_discount_invoiced>4.0000</base_discount_invoiced>
<amount_refunded>39.9900</amount_refunded>
<base_amount_refunded>39.9900</base_amount_refunded>
<row_total>39.9900</row_total>
<base_row_total>39.9900</base_row_total>
<row_invoiced>39.9900</row_invoiced>
<base_row_invoiced>39.9900</base_row_invoiced>
<row_weight>0.0000</row_weight>
<weee_tax_applied>a:0:{}</weee_tax_applied>
<weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_amount>
<weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_amount>
<base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>0.0000</base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount>
<weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_disposition>
<weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</weee_tax_row_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_disposition>
<base_weee_tax_row_disposition>0.0000</base_weee_tax_row_disposition>
</complexObjectArray>
</items>
<payment>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<amount_ordered>159.7100</amount_ordered>
<shipping_amount>4.9900</shipping_amount>
<base_amount_ordered>159.7100</base_amount_ordered>
<base_shipping_amount>4.9900</base_shipping_amount>
<method>sagepaydirectpro</method>
<cc_type>*****</cc_type>
<cc_last4>****</cc_last4>
<cc_owner>**** ****</cc_owner>
<cc_exp_month>**</cc_exp_month>
<cc_exp_year>****</cc_exp_year>
<cc_ss_start_month>0</cc_ss_start_month>
<cc_ss_start_year>0</cc_ss_start_year>
<payment_id>34</payment_id>
</payment>
<status_history>
<complexObjectArray>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<created_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</created_at>
<is_customer_notified>0</is_customer_notified>
<status>complete</status>
</complexObjectArray>
<complexObjectArray>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<created_at>2015-06-04 11:59:30</created_at>
<is_customer_notified>2</is_customer_notified>
<status>processing</status>
<comment>Refunded amount of £154.72 offline.</comment>
</complexObjectArray>
<complexObjectArray>
<parent_id>34</parent_id>
<created_at>2015-05-28 12:21:50</created_at>
<is_customer_notified>1</is_customer_notified>
<status>processing</status>
</complexObjectArray>
</status_history>
</result>
</ns1:salesOrderInfoResponseParam>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: First, which version of the api are you using? What does your current code look like?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: If you can update the question with the code then I can try to help you.

Comment: @Muk My code is there!

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Have you refereed Tim Hallman's answer? I think it should solve your problem.I can provide the solution using PHP.

Comment: @Muk  I've seen his answer.  I can make the call fine - it is just not returning the coupon_code field.

Comment: @Muk Worked it out - see my answer.  Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like salesOrderInfo doesn't return the coupon_code, but salesOrderList does - I had to dig around inside the WSDL to discover that.  Doesn't seem very logical, but looks like Tim Hallman's answer actually refers to salesOrderList and not salesOrderInfo.  The following code in VB.NET returns it...

```
Dim mc As New Magento.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortTypeClient()
Dim token = mc.login("TheUserName", "TheAPIKey")
Dim f As New Magento.filters()
f.filter = New Magento.associativeEntity() {
    New Magento.associativeEntity With {.key = "increment_id", .value = 100000024}}

Dim sol = mc.salesOrderList(token, f)
```

The result is then in `sol(0).coupon_code`

Comment: salesOrderList will return a list of sales orders, whereas salesOrderInfo will return the information for a particular sales order.

Comment: @TimHallman Yes, and I expected salesOrderInfo to have at least the same fields that salesOrderList does, but Info doesn't have the coupon_code and List does!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version (1 or 2) and which type (SOAP or RESTful) api you're using will depend on the correct method to retrieve the data, but either way using method `salesOrderInfo` will return an array with coupon code like

```
array
  'state' => string 'new' (length=3)
  'status' => string 'pending' (length=7)
  'coupon_code' => null
  'protect_code' => string 'defe18' (length=6)
  'shipping_description' => string 'Flat Rate - Fixed' (length=17)
...
```

I am not sure how to write the code in VB.net, but in php V2 would look like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http:/magentoinstall.local/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

$session = $client->login('user', 'pass');    
$filter = new StdClass();
$filter->filter = array(array("key" => "sales_order", "value" => "100000024"));
$list = $client->salesOrderInfo($session, $filter);
```

So I'm wondering if/how you are passing filters through your VB script.

Comment: I've updated the question.  It doesn't appear to be present in SOAP v2 with WS-I compliance enabled.  I've checked with Fiddler to be sure.

Comment: Can you try setting your store id before/during the request? `cart_store_id `.

Comment: salesOrderInfo just seems to take an integer described as orderIncrementId as the second parameter according to the WSDL in WS-I mode at least.  It does return the correct order.  I can't see any way to set the store id in V2, but since it returns the correct order, I can't see how that would be likely to make any difference anyway

Comment: Worked it out - see my answer.  Thanks for trying!